# ImmutableMap turns into a HashMap when passed through Intent

Tags: android, guava, android-guava

I am using Guava collections in an Android project.
Just noticed the following behavior:

In `Activity1`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("extra1", ImmutableMap.of("key1", "value1"));
startActivity(i);
```

In `Activity2`:

```
Activity2::onCreate(...) {
  ImmutableMap<String,String> map = 
         (ImmutableMap<String,String>)getIntent()
              .getSerializableExtra("extra1");
  // above line throws ClassCastException!
}
```

Once executed, code in the second snippet throws this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
>   com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap

So at some point `ImmutableMap` gets turned into a `HashMap`.
I wonder why is that and what can I do to avoid this?

P.S. If I print this to debug output right after constructing/receiving an Intent:

```
intent.getSerializableExtra("extra1").getClass().getSimpleName());
// ^^^^ prints SingletonImmutableBiMap in Activity1
// ^^^^ prints HashMap in Activity2
```

Comment: I would guess it's because ImmutableMap has it's own serialization. HashMap appears to be imported in ImmutableMap but I don't see where it's used. Unsure of how it would resolve to HashMap. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Intent` extras are passed around as [parcels](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html), which is a high-performance IPC transport (think high-performance serialization). When parcelled, your ImmutableMap is [written like all Map implementations](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#L1195), and thus it is later [read as a HashMap](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#L2015).

I don't think you can avoid this. If you really want to work with an `ImmutableMap`, you'd need to use `ImmutableMap.copyOf()` to copy the HashMap's content into an ImmutableMap.

```
Activity2::onCreate(...) {
  ImmutableMap<String,String> map = ImmutableMap.copyOf(
         (Map<String,String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("extra1")
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh, nice find, thank you! I suspected it will turn out to be something like this.